# Need to get the response status after error handle errors

Tags: javascript, fetch

My problem is when the fetch response status is 403 the response return HTML not json, but when the code reach the if statment i cant access the response status anymore.

```
const response = await fetch(
   \\\\\\ Fetch infos \\\\\
).then(
    response => {
        return response.json().then(data => ({
            status: response.status,
            data

        })).catch(err => console.log(err))
    });

if (response.status == 403) {
  \\\\ Stuf \\\\\
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await fetch(URL)
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok && response.status === 403) {
      // Write your logic here and return
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => ({
    data,
  }));
```

Comment: This answer could possibly be improved by [edit]ing to explain how/why it solves the problem. For example, what was wrong with the asker's code?

Answer (score 0):

Before returning `response.json()` check the status and if `response.ok`

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    if (response.ok && response.status === 200) {
      return response.json()
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
      // do what ever you want to do
    }

  })
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: return response.json().then(data => ({
            status: response.status,
            data. how i do this?